# React Native version mismatch

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Getting the following message when I init a new project and then launch the Xcode emulator:

> React-Native Version Mismatch
>
> Javascript Version 0.50.1
>   Native version: 0.50.0
>
> Make sure you have rebuilt the native code. ...

Does anyone know what is going on here and can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 460, accepted):

This is what I've done with it:

> Close all terminals and run build again.

You may forget to close nodejs terminal from another project, and they happen to have installed different react version.

So the code fetches from nodejs server conflicts with the native one.

Comment: what if I don't want to close my currently opened terminals (I have apps running there) ? Is there another workaround ?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev you can just close that specific terminal opened by react-native, which shows `Bundling 'index.android.js'  100.0% (1/1), done`.

Comment: force fully using react dependency version in `build.gradle` worked. thanks @Val

Comment: Closed all terminals and used: `react-native run-ios`

Comment: also run `pod install` if you are using cocoapods.

Comment: Wow, just closing the terminal and stopping other builds works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This worked for me, I had another terminal running for another project so when I ran my VS Code, the terminal server for the other project was causing this problem. Killing all terminals and restarting the server worked

Comment: If you have multiple apps running change the port |npm react-native run-android --port 8082|

Answer (score 43):

In case you created your react-native app using create-react-native-app. You should have a app.json (expo). and a package.json file, check if the expo versions match and change accordingly. For example in my case the problem was that in the app.json file I had a 25.0.0 version for the **expo sdkVersion attribute**, I change that to 23.0.0 and everything worked.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^23.0.4",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.50.4"
  }
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "23.0.0" // before was 25.0.0
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Quick update: you may not use a direct npm module for your react-native package and instead have a tarball. If that's the case, you can use react-native status to verify your version of RN. :)

Answer (score 16):

Just go to your `android/app/build.gradle` and then add to the `dependencies` section:

```
dependencies{
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.50.3") { force = true } 
}
```

/// the react native version can be found in package.json

Comment: where do I change for ios

Comment: what's the equivalent change in package.json?

Comment: I know this is an old answer but "force" is not deprecated. (and also compile is now implement)

Answer (score 9):

just force react native version in your android's app level gradle file, in the `dependencies` section.

```
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.52.0") { force = true }
```

worked for me

Comment: This worked for me. I have 0.53.3. I added a force with 0.53.3, restarted terminals, ran `npm start -- --reset-cache` and ran `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 8):

If you're running your React Native app through Expo, upgrading React Native is liable to cause this error (as noted at https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/923).

If that's your scenario, your options are:

1. Bump Expo (which is listed in your `package.json`) to a version that is compatible with your React Native version (*if* one exists, which may not be the case - judging by the linked issue, I figure that Expo support trails React Native releases).
2. Discard your changes, delete and reinstall your Node modules, [Eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) from Expo, and then (after checking that you can still run your app post-ejection) try your upgrade again.

Comment: Expo only supports react-native up to 59.8 at the time of writing. For expo/react-native compatibility, see https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/overview/#sdk-version

(it's not the exact same cause of error as the OP, but seems relevant to note.)

Answer (score 8):

For Android developers who couldn't get it fixed by just closing and rebuilding, Manually uninstall the app on the emulator/device.

Comment: Uninstalling the app from IOS simulator worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I've never seen this error before, but whenever I can't get Xcode and React-Native to play well together, I do a couple of things.  Check what version of Xcode I'm working with. If it needs to be updated, I update it.  Then clearing watchman and the cache are the second place I go.  I don't use the reset cache command.  It always says that I need to verify the cache, so I skip that (you can do it though, I just get confused). I use rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* to get rid of any cached builds.  If that doesn't work, I try to build the app in Xcode, then work my way from there, to build it with react-native run-ios.  With this error message, it seems you might start by trying to build it with Xcode.  Hope that helps...let me know your progress with it.  Good luck! (Also, you could update to RN 0.51 as another attempt to get your versions synced.)

Comment: The other thing is that I played around with expo. Wonder if that messed things up

Comment: You could just do npm install --save react-native@0.51  But, I'd try building it with Xcode first.  Have you done that yet? If you need help, let me know.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem for the longest time and none of the above solutions helped. I was in the middle of upgrading react native in a `create-react-native-app` project until I found out that not all versions of Expo support the latest React Native.

Found this page linked in the documentation that shows which version combinations of React Native, React, and Expo are officially supported:

Source: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md

Editing the `app.json` and `package.json` files to match the corresponding versions and running `npm install` got everything working again.

Answer (score 6):

I am using a physical device, in my case this solved the problem:

1. Uninstall the app
2. `lsof -i :8081`
3. `kill -9 PID`
4. Rebuild the app (`react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`)

Comment: Simply killing all PIDs from `lsof -i :8081` and rebuilding did it for me on iOS Simulator.

Comment: The same here - tried Rimraf node_modules, npm start —reset-cache, etc - nothing worked. Then I did as above - uninstalled app, used taskkill /im node.exe and taskkill /f /PID(number given in last step, of existing PID), then react-native run-android. Worked a treat!

Answer (score 5):

In your build.gradle file add the following

```
implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.51.0") {
    force = true;
}
```

replace `0.51.0` with the version in your package.json

Answer (score 5):

I have tried the solutions above but adding this to **AndroidManifest.xml** seems to fix it.

```
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: It worked like charm.. this is the reason I will never like android.. There is always a magic word that solves your problems which have driven you crazy for many hours.

Comment: It worked for me this time.

Comment: Yeap. this save my time!! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the dependencies again. That worked for me-

1.) `yarn/npm install`
2.) `yarn/npm start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 4):

It happens sometimes when you try to run without closing the node server, in which the previous app was running, so try restarting React.To do so, just run the following commands:

```
1. To kill current processes
killall node -9 

2. To Start React  Native
react-native start 

3. Then Run android
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Running this command also worked for me  "killall node"

Answer (score 4):

For my case I'm facing it on iOS, and I've tried to reset and clear all cache using below command but failed too, despite many comments saying that the root cause is there is react packager running somewhere accidentally, I've restarted my mac and the problem still remained.

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install && yarn start --reset-cache
```

The solution is, to delete the build folder @ `/ios/build`, then execute `react-native run-ios` solved it

Answer (score 3):

The fix we did was to make sure the ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables were set up prior to the build.

First, run the below two commands then the build the app for the device.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/MyFiles/applications/androidsdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it was due to `react-native` version in `dependency` section of `package.json` file. It was:

```
"dependencies": {
"expo": "^27.0.1",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "~0.55.0"
}
```

I chaged it to:

```
"dependencies": {
"expo": "^27.0.1",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.52.0"
}
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case installing a new virtual device helped. Now I am using 1 device per app.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me :

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 2):

For others with the same problem on iOS with CocoaPods:

I tried all of the solutions above, without luck. I have some packages with native dependencies in my project, and some of those needed pod modules being installed. The problem was that React was specified in my Podfile, but the React pod didn't automatically get upgraded by using `react-native-git-upgrade`.

The fix is to upgrade all installed pods, by running `cd ios && pod install`.

Answer (score 2):

Expo users - make sure your `app.json` sdk version and `package.json` expo version are (may be equal) compatible to each other.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution for a new expo user.

Answer (score 2):

For me, who is running with a monorepo, there was a hidden react-native version inside yarn.lock. It was not present in any package.json, but was never deleted.

I removed that particular react-native version from yarn.lock, and did a

```
yarn install
```

This cleaned out alot of old stuff and made sure that things was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue using Expo and iOS Simulator. What worked for me was erasing the Simulator in `Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings...`

Comment: I am pretty sure that this can be accomplished by just uninstalling the Expo app from the emulator. No need to everything.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same issue while building my react native app for android and I did the following which worked for me.

The "JavaScript version 0.50.1" in the error console is the react-native version in your `package.json` file. Make sure it is the same version as "Native version 0.50.0" in the error console.

1. I have Updated the react-native version to the "Native Version 0.50.0" as prompted in the error console.
2. Rebuild the app `react-native run-android`.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Fix:

1. Delete the **package-lock.json**
2. **Run:** `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && rm -rf node_modules/&& npm install`

If the problem persists, try to execute the **project** directly from the ***Xcode***

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (NOT using expo & Android build)

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.2"
}
```

And app.json

```
{
  "sdkVersion": "27"
}
```

resolved the issue

Comment: This is true especially if you're using Expo. Check out Expo's upgrade docs for more info:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to build and run a React Native app from WebStorm and ran into this problem. The simple solution for me was:

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

On macOS, if `watchman` is not already installed, install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install watchman
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed the `expo` version manually. I got the same issue because I forgot to update **sdkVersion** in **app.json** and **babel-preset-expo** in **package.json**

After that run: `expo r -c` to clear cache and start the app.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer is Published in 2020,
Fix this Error in 3 steps:

First step: I changed the value of `expo` in `package.json` file to the latest supported version, according to expo documents(visit [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/overview/)).

Second step: I changed the value of `sdkVersion` in `app.json` file to the same value of `expo` in `package.json`.( equal number to last step).

Third step : I changed the value of `react-native` in `package.json` file to the same value of `React Native Version` , according to expo documents(visit [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/overview/)).

now your ready to go.

use `npm install` to install specified version of dependencies and then `npm start` to run the project

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me 18/06/20 - i used SDK version 38 for steps 1 & 2 and then "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.1.tar.gz", for step 3

Answer (score 1):

I got this classing when TypeScript type definitions mismatched.

E.G `react-native` at 0.61.5 in `dependencies` and `@types/react-native` at 0.60.0 in `devDependencies`.

As soon as I updated devDependencies it worked. Didn't have to restart anything.

Answer (score 1):

edit your package.json for your javascript version

```
"react-native": "^0.50.1",
```

after run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

for my problem fix this when change emulator with API Level below 28. this source of problem because of network changes in API Level 28 and above. fix this problem by add

```
<application
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to androidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fix, but in my case, I had multiple RN apps installed on my device and I was unknowingly attempting to 'Reload` from within the wrong application. (I'm developing two apps simultaneously at the moment) So make sure you're in the correct application!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the version of your react-native specified in your package.json (under dependencies - react-native) to the same as 'Native Version' shown in the error message. Then run 'npm install' again.

Comment: any idea how to downgrade to the version mentioned in the package.json?

Comment: in your package.json you should see something like "react-native": "^0.55.0" under "dependencies". Change that number (0.55.0 in this example) to your desired version and run "npm install" again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure also that the wifi is enabled in your emulator

Answer (score 0):

Opene projectdir/android/app/build.gradle

Try:

compile("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.51.0") { force = true }

Instead of
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.51.0" { force = true }

Ref.:  [Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19259#issuecomment-389067216)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my android physical device does not connect to the js server running on my development machine. So i have to manually set the debug server host & port on my android device.

Comment: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` helped for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be especially applicable for Android Studio 3.2 or newer users, as this did not seem to happen before upgrading.

If you didn't change the version of React Native in your configuration (`package.json`, `build.gradle`), the problem with the version mismatch could come from undetected changes to project files after checking out another commit in git. To overcome that, make sure to:

- Clean the build: `Build > Clean Project`
- Sync Project with Gradle files: next to the `Stop` button on navigation bar
- Make Project: first button in navigation bar with an hammer icon
- And finally Run / Debug app

This would also overcome the `Session 'app': Error Installing APK` error that might happen due to Instant Run once the app is uninstalled from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Close the nodejs terminal and Rebuild.

Comment: This duplicates the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47764280/1709587).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by deleting node_modules and running npm install again

Answer (score 0):

I update the react-native version: 0.57.4 to 0.59.8 and i getting the following message "React-Native Version Mismatch"

This solution works for me:

```
1.- In the folder of the project, update all the code react-native in the Android Studio:

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

2.- Go to Android Studio and FILE->>INVALIDATE CACHES/RESTART
3.- In Android Studio, BUILD->>CLEAN PROJECT
4.- In Android Studio, BUILD->>REBUILD PROJECT
5.- Delete App in simulator or Devices
6.- Run...
```

I hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

All those answers about changing versions to match whatever were wrong for me.

What the error does not tell you is where that version is coming from. Running a search of all files, I found that there was only 1 place where the javascript version was defined:
The problem was that the bundle (`\android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle`) needed to be regenerated as it was containing older versions compared to the installed bundle.

In order to regenerate that file, I had to run the following command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

And because I had upgraded my react-native, running this command gave me a few errors I needed to resolve (mainly installing new dependencies).

Clearing cache, reloading in android studio, reloading react, reloading the terminal, creating a new project and transfering the files, running watchman, all did not work as that specific bundle file happens to be tracked in the Git repo.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`expo update 39.0.0 --npm`

As my expo version was 38(Check in package.json).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from [stackoverflow another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726261/react-native-console-error-react-native-version-mismatch) and I like to place it here.

> First step: I changed the value of expo in package.json file to the latest supported version, according to expo documents[(visit here)](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/?redirected).

> Second step: I changed the value of sdkVersion in app.json file to the same value of expo in package.json.( equal number to last step).

if `sdkVersion` not exists in your app.json file, please add it like this.
`"sdkVersion": "xx.x.x"` (same as expo version in package.json)

> Third step : I changed the value of react-native in package.json file to the same value of React Native Version , according to expo documents[(visit here)](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/?redirected).

Comment: "✔ Removed deprecated sdkVersion field from app.json." sdkVersion is deprecated as of now (Expo44)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your application from your device and then install it again

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue after manually updating my packages.
Removing all projects from the `Expo Go` app **and** running `expo update` fix the problem automatically for me.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a new emulator and closing all terminals used to work for me and only when I ran from Android Studio. Now that's not working anymore.

A bit counterintuitive but I noticed that when I ran from Android Studio received that error the metro bundler terminal wasn't launching.

[image]

So I executed `npx react-native run-android` from terminal (which didn't work but it did launch the metro bundler) , then I ran that app from Android Studio and it worked!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Close js Server terminals and run build again

Answer (score -1):

I updated the SDK version in app.json to match with the react native SDK version in package.json to fix this issue

In app.json

```
"sdkVersion": "37.0.0",
```

In package.json

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, I had to open multiple node js terminal for react native and forgot to close before running app into my android device.
I close the terminal and run again and it loaded the page successfully