# React Native version Mismatch after updating React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting into React Native, and right now I got an error that I can't fix, after updating RN, this is what I got while I'm using Expo:

```
React Native version Mismatch
JavaScript version: 0.51.0
Native version: 0.50.3
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question here I think.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Version Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch)

Comment: You shouldn't be updating RN directly but wait for when expo releases a new SDK.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian good to know, and now i'm asking what's the  "Javascript version" ??

Comment: What does JavaScript version mean? The React library ? Recommend you look at bottom of this post, https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v24-0-0-is-now-available-bfcac3b50d51  as always, look at documentation before reaching for SO.

Answer (score 2):

In your `build.gradle` file add the following:

```
implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.51.0") {
    force = true;
}
```

and replace `0.51.0` with the version in your `package.json`