# Lock React Native version in xcode IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have been using **React Native** for the past 4 of months working both on **Android** and **IOS**. According to React Native Docs there will be an updated version of React Native every month. So, I keep updating it every month which is good, but the problem is I am using a couple of npm packages which is getting outdated due to `react-native` update which in-turn causes errors in my project.

For **Android**, we can lock the `react-native` version by specifying the version number in **gradle**. And for the **Javascript** part we can lock it in `package.json`. But for IOS I am not able to find anything like that.

So, is there way to lock the `react-native` version in **IOS** xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make your `package.json` file at root path - *react-native* version to fixed number. for example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-native": "0.50.4",
}
```

So every time you do `npm install`, that given version will be installed. without postfix `^` it will never be upgraded.

The *react-native* version of iOS is just a project / static library import from `node_module/react-native/Libraries` folder, via `react-native link`.

**Update 1:**

Take `RCTAnimation.xcodeproj` in project for example,
you can find it locate at `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTAnimation.xcodeproj`.

[image]

Comment: If that's how it works, then do you have any idea about what is causing this error?

React Native version mismatch:
Javascript version: 0.50.3
Native version: 0.51.0

Comment: If that's your case -- version mismatch, you might run into this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch

Comment: Updated my answer about the relationship between XCode project and node_modules.

Comment: Awesome! Works great :)