# React Native Version Mismatch - JavaScript 0.52.0 and Native 0.56.0

Tags: react-native

I have a error for running a android app like image below:

[image]

For package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Training",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

and the `android/app/gradle.properties`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules
}
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch - try checking answers of this

Comment: I have tried like
1. compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.52.0") { force = true }
2. compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.56.0") { force = true }
3. close all terminal + rebuild

they are not works for me... @KirankumarDafda

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all terminals (therefore stopping all running bundlers)
2. optionally: clear caches
3. optionally: to make sure your build uses the correct version you may run: `./gradlew androidDependencies` and check the output which react native version your build actually uses (0.56 or 0.52)
4. deinstall the app from the device and freshly reinstall it!

Comment: Thank you for your concern @JimVanB

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by:

1. Restart PC (linux mint 17.3)
2. Wipe Data for the emulator
3. And run final command: `react-native run-android`