# React Native - console.error: 'React Native version mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, version

I am using EXPO and React Native, the app work running completely fine until it suddenly stopped when I made a new file and even when I deleted it, the error stayed.

I have updated React Native to V0.56.0 but it is still showing the error:

> console.error: 'React Native version mismatch.

Javascript version: 0.56.0
Native Version: 0.52.0

Before I updated it was:

Javascript version: 0.54.0
Native Version: 0.52.0

and still causing the same error?

Any ideas on how I fix this and which command I use to update the Native Version?

Comment: [This is worked for me ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch) **First answer worked for me**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `package.json` file inside your project folder

Where you can find code like this

```
"dependencies": {
    .....
    "react-native": "^0.54.0",
    ......
},
```

change the `react-native` version to `0.54` and save file.

Then go to the terminal and redirect to your project folder and hit the command

```
npm install  && expo start -c
```

Answer (score 4):

This Answer is Published in 2020 and updated in 2021,
Fix this Error in 3 steps:

First step: I changed the value of `expo` in `package.json` file to the latest supported version, according to expo documents(visit [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/overview/)).

Second step: I changed the value of `sdkVersion` in `app.json` file to the same value of `expo` in `package.json`.( equal number to last step).

Third step : I changed the value of `react-native` in `package.json` file to the same value of `React Native Version` , according to expo documents(visit [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/overview/)).

now your ready to go.

use `npm install` to install specified version of dependencies and then `npm start` to run the project

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this

```
$ sudo npm install babel-upgrade -g
$ react-native-git-upgrade
$ npx babel-upgrade --write
$ sudo npm install babel-upgrade -g
$ npx babel-upgrade --write --install
$ react-native-git-upgrade
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
$ rm -rf ios/Pods
$ cd ios
$ pod cache clean --all
$ pod repo update && pod install
$ cd ..
$ npm install
$ ./android/gradlew clean -p ./android/
$ rm -rf ios/build
$ react-native run-ios
$ react-native run-android
$ cd ios/
$ pod update yoga
$ pod update React/RCTNetwork
$ pod repo update
$ pod update
$ cd ..
$ pod update
$ cd ..
$ react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Javascript was one version behind the installed native version,

So, I changed the sdk version to just 1 behind
Changed this line in my package.json
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz",

to
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz",

and saved the file, and app started working (Didn't even restart the app)