# How can i update the JavaScript in a react Native Project?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I built the app in the Emulator. but the error i get is very strange:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't know what you want, what your environment looks like, etc... Please ask your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you followed the steps suggested within that error message: *"clear the watchman and packages caches"*? Please explain what you have tried and include the relevant source code, thank you.

Comment: @Matthijs did you see the pic i sent? i don't know how to explain more clearly??
javascript version is 0.55 . native version is 0.57.. i want to update javascript so it matches the native version

Comment: @LadiOra We'd like to know in what emulator you are working and some background information. However, your question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch

Comment: @Matthijs Emulator:GenyMotion



node error:

error: bundling failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In D:\ParsaApp\ParsaApp\node_modules\babel-preset-react-native-stage-0\index.js

Comment: Please try to solve your error with the related question that I mentioned in my previous comment. If that doesn't solve your problem, please *update* your question with possible solutions you tried.

Comment: @Matthijs i tries ALL of the solutions in that post you mentioned but NOTHING works! :((

Comment: Please update your question with information about **what** you tried and tell us what goes wrong while you did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem. there were multiple JDK and JRE versions installed on my PC. i deleted the older JDKs  and java versions and now there are no issues anymore...