# React Native version Mismatch - Native version: 0.59.5

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am getting this error on Android simulator:

React Native version mismatch:
Javascript version: 0.58.5
Native version: 0.59.5

I have upgraded React Native, modules, Android studio and pretty much everything i could. Everything works fine on iOS, this happens only on Android. Build is succesful

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.3.3",
    "latlon-geohash": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.16",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        //mavenLocal()        
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
      
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

/*
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}*/





   dependencies {
        implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
        implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
        implementation project(':react-native-maps') 
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
        implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    
        implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7") {
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        } 
    
        implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0") {
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        } 
    
        implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6") {
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        }
    }
```

I have tried closing all terminals, yarn install, creating new android device. I am guessing it has to do with actual version of the React Native in Package.json, but it is the 0.59.5 and when I searched whole project I cant find any reference to 0.58.5 anywhere.

Comment: can you try removing `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` files before running `yarn install`?

Comment: close your terminal and run again. it's working.

Comment: just close the app on the emulator and rerun it from expo ui.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch

Comment: @kenmistry if i will remove the node_modules folder, will i have to reinstall all the modules again ? I mean all the setup when doing first time installation of a package ?

Comment: @CosmicSeizure no further setup required, i believe. It simply recreates the node-modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem with help from github forum. This error was caused in my case by having Android 9 in simulator. Installing new device with Android version 8 fixed the issue.

Comment: A similar solution, creating a new device with a newer recommended version per the android device tool worked for me as well.

Comment: @OsoGrizz Can you please clarify what device and version you are using ? I tried using Pixel2 API 29 with Android 9+ ( JS 0.58.5, NV 0.59.5 ) and its still throwing mismatch error. So i am still forced to use Simulator Android 8.1, where it works fine.

Comment: I can't be sure about what config I was using prior anymore, but I am now using; Pixel 3 XL API 28 Android 9.0 (Google API's), react-native: 0.59.8

Comment: @CosmicSeizure facing some similar issues, so I'm curious: what do you mean by API 29/Android 9+? In terms of a single device's OS, API 29 means Android 10.0, and Android 9.0 would equate to API 28, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Close all terminal and  IDE and Launch it again. It will work**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have RN versions in `package.json` same as it is in `android/app/build.gradle`, it should look like:

in package.json

`"react-native": "0.59.5",`

and in `android/app/build.gradle`

`implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.5") { force = true  }`

**Edit:**
Can you please also check that the packager and the emulator/device are in same network and the JS bundle is fetched from right locations ?
It seems your application is not getting updated while building, it is stuck in the old code.

Comment: Can you make sure that the React Native node module you are using is having right version in its package.json ?

Comment: I have looked into the Package.json inside React Native node module and it seems to be correct:

{
  "name": "react-native",
  "version": "0.59.5",

Comment: I have added an edit section in the answer. Check if that helps.

Comment: @SurajMalviya How do you check if the packager and emulator are in the same network? And the JS bundle is fetched from the right location?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

package.json

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4",
"react-native-maps": "0.25.0",
```

build.gradle :

```
googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1" 
 androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had `workdir/android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` left from the previous build from another branch where I used older RN.

Running `react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` fixed it for me.