# React Native Version Mismatch 0.60.4

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

After upgrading to react-native:0.60.4 I have been unable to run my app and I am getting a react-native version mismatch error.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.60.4",
    "react-native-btr": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-overlay": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-progress-bar": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1",
    "react-navigation-fluid-transitions": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^3.2.2",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Try to clean and build your project again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Version Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch)

Comment: @remeus I don't think it is a duplicate as all the answers in the thread you link are garbage and do not work. (I know because I tried them all.) They all focus on downgrading React-Native and not upgrading the JS part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed by my own way.

1. Create another empty project
2. Copy your resources + packages.json to new project
3. Do npm install in new project

Issue solved.

Answer (score 2):

1- **Close all terminal**/bash screen

2- Open new bash and **go to project folder**

`cd ~/Documents/projects/myProject`

3- **Run** your project

`react-native run-ios //react-native run-android`

4- npm start **in your path**

`myProject$ npm start`

best!

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact solution to this, because all systems and installations and variations versions are endless.

[image: error screenshot here]

## So in order to best resolve this without pulling your hair out, is to

1. Update your `react-native` by using `npx react-native upgrade`
2. Just in case also install React Native globally on your system like this  `npm install -g react-native-cli`
3. Then create a brand new EXPO or React Native project with `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`
4. Then within your `package.json` view the versions of `react` and `react-native` from the new project and compare them to your working project

For example this was my working project

```
        "expo-barcode-scanner": "~8.2.1",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.2.1",
        "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
        "react": "~16.11.0",
        "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
        "react-native": "^0.61.4",
```

This was my new project Package.json

```
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
```

Then finally I used the `react` and `react-native` version from my new project and it all worked perfectly

here is the final code for my working project

```
        "expo-barcode-scanner": "~8.2.1",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.2.1",
        "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
        "react": "~16.11.0",
        "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
        "react-native": "~0.62.2",
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect. React Native is up to date:>npx react-native upgrade
info No version passed. Fetching latest...
warn Specified version "0.63.4" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "^0.63.4" semver range. No need to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the request message to you to execute is correct. Execute the message.

```
watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache
```