# JavaScript version mismatch in React Native

Tags: react-native

> console.error: "React native version mismatch.

**JavaScript version: 0.55.4**
**Native version: 0.59.2**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604603/module-appregistry-is-not-registered-callable-module-calling-runapplication/51304124#51304124

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Version Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

it's just a console.error, I had the same problem after update.
Try to:

```
 close all terminals and reopen.
```

If you want to remove the alert, go to:

```
node_modules > react-native > Libraries > Core > ReactNativeVersionCheck.js
```

and find a line where:

```
console.error and replace it to console.log
```

it will dismiss the red Box...