# React native version mismatch: native version: 0.61.5, javascript version: 0.57.7

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react-native app, which does not use expo. I get the following error:

```
 React Native version mismatch.
                             │ 
                             │ JavaScript version: 0.57.7
                             │ Native version: 0.61.5
                             │ 
                             └ Make sure that you have rebuilt the native code. If the problem persists try clearing the Watchman and packager caches with `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`.
```

I have done everything mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch)
and nothing has worked so far.

I have updated react-native version to 0.61.5 . It is installed and it is also mentioned in package.json. I have also updated all packages in packages.json.

The project also uses react-navigation. In @react-navigation file in node modules, in  native/package.json file, it is the only place that `"react-native": "^0.57.7"`, is mentioned under devDependencies.  I have installed the latest react-navigation, `4.0.10`.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent this issue, you should force React Native version in `android/app/build.gradle` file use

```
compile("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5") { force = true }
```

Change 0.57.7 as per your react-native version.

Comment: have you upgraded your Node.js recently ? you can downgrade it, for me  it worked.