# React native verion mismatch JavaScript version :0.57.7 , native version :0. 59.5

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried to reset cache and watch-del-all still facing this issue

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Version Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763824/react-native-version-mismatch)