# getPropertyAsObject: property -- react native from 0.62.0 to 0.64.0

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to upgrade my react-native project from version 0.62.0 to 0.64.0

when i run the app on android, i get the following error:

Error: getPropertyAsObject: property "callFunctionReturnResultAndFlushedQueue" is undefined, expected an Object.

I have cleaned all the caches and run :
`npx react-native run-android && npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Also when i open the chrome debugger i get the following error: React Native version mismatch. JavaScript version: 0.64.0 Native version: 0.62.2

Comment: It would be better, If u share what u have done to upgrade the version. If possible, you can share the doc link which u have followed. Also share your react and gradle version.

Comment: I just followed https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/
versions:     "react": "17.0.1",
                    "react-native": "0.64.0",
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this problem.
In my project, i am using [react-native-v8](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-v8) (Runtime engine for react-Native).
And in order to use this, you need to match your versions of v8-android && react-native-v8 with your new react-native version.
I hope this helps the ones in need because it was frustrating me for a while.

Comment: this is not clear what the solution is

Comment: @prog_24 Are you using react-native-v8 in your react native project?

Comment: No. Oh I see, its a package. I think you should probably make that clear in your answer since the name sounds really similar to react native one might assume it was an extension

Comment: not at all clear what the solution is here.

Comment: i kept this issue open in order to help any person that is stuck in upgrading the react native project version.
My problem is that i was  using another package [react-native-v8](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-v8) and that package is depending on the exact react-native version accordingly.